# Hbase 2.2.5 shell scan table is giving issue

Tags: hadoop, hbase, cloudera, apache-phoenix

hbase shell scan table is giving the following error

```
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Failed after attempts=8, exceptions:
2020-07-17T16:46:06.573Z, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1595004366529, pause=100, maxAttempts=8}, java.net.ConnectException: Call to bob-Lenovo/127.0.1.1:16020 failed on connection exception: org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: bob-Lenovo/127.0.1.1:16020
2020-07-17T16:46:06.679Z, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1595004366529, pause=100, maxAttempts=8}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.FailedServerException: Call to bob-Lenovo/127.0.1.1:16020 failed on local exception: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.FailedServerException: This server is in the failed servers list: bob-Lenovo/127.0.1.1:16020
2020-07-17T16:46:06.881Z, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1595004366529, pause=100, maxAttempts=8}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.FailedServerException: Call to bob-Lenovo/127.0.1.1:16020 failed on local exception: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.FailedServerException: This server is in the failed servers list: bob-Lenovo/127.0.1.1:16020
2020-07-17T16:46:07.188Z, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1595004366529, pause=100, maxAttempts=8}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.FailedServerException: Call to bob-Lenovo/127.0.1.1:16020 failed on local exception: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.FailedServerException: This server is in the failed servers list: bob-Lenovo/127.0.1.1:16020
2020-07-17T16:46:07.695Z, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1595004366529, pause=100, maxAttempts=8}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.FailedServerException: Call to bob-Lenovo/127.0.1.1:16020 failed on local exception: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.FailedServerException: This server is in the failed servers list: bob-Lenovo/127.0.1.1:16020
2020-07-17T16:46:08.714Z, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1595004366529, pause=100, maxAttempts=8}, java.net.ConnectException: Call to bob-Lenovo/127.0.1.1:16020 failed on connection exception: org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: bob-Lenovo/127.0.1.1:16020
2020-07-17T16:46:10.726Z, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1595004366529, pause=100, maxAttempts=8}, java.net.ConnectException: Call to bob-Lenovo/127.0.1.1:16020 failed on connection exception: org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: bob-Lenovo/127.0.1.1:16020
2020-07-17T16:46:14.748Z, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1595004366529, pause=100, maxAttempts=8}, java.net.ConnectException: Call to bob-Lenovo/127.0.1.1:16020 failed on connection exception: org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: bob-Lenovo/127.0.1.1:16020

    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerImpl.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCallerImpl.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ResultBoundedCompletionService$QueueingFuture.run(ResultBoundedCompletionService.java:80)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Call to bob-Lenovo/127.0.1.1:16020 failed on connection exception: org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: bob-Lenovo/127.0.1.1:16020
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.IPCUtil.wrapException(IPCUtil.java:177)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.onCallFinished(AbstractRpcClient.java:392)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.access$100(AbstractRpcClient.java:97)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$3.run(AbstractRpcClient.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$3.run(AbstractRpcClient.java:419)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.Call.callComplete(Call.java:117)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.Call.setException(Call.java:132)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.BufferCallBeforeInitHandler.userEventTriggered(BufferCallBeforeInitHandler.java:92)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:326)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:312)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:304)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.userEventTriggered(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1426)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:326)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:312)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireUserEventTriggered(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:924)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.NettyRpcConnection.failInit(NettyRpcConnection.java:179)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.NettyRpcConnection.access$500(NettyRpcConnection.java:71)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.NettyRpcConnection$3.operationComplete(NettyRpcConnection.java:267)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.NettyRpcConnection$3.operationComplete(NettyRpcConnection.java:261)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:502)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:495)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:474)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:415)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:540)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:533)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:114)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.fulfillConnectPromise(AbstractNioChannel.java:327)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:343)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:665)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:612)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:529)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:491)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:905)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: bob-Lenovo/127.0.1.1:16020
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:714)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:327)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:340)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    ... 11 more
```

This crash happened the second time after I am trying to connect Hbase with Phoenix (5.0) if I will delete Hbase directory and Zookeeper data directory and come up again with all data then it works fine, what could be the issue and how to resolve it without data deletion?

Answer (score 0):

Here the issue is with HBase installation it was running in a standalone environment and starting Zookeeper privately in its own context. To run Phoenix properly HBase should be installed in a distributed mode and zookeeper should start separately.